# Inverse Perspective Mapping OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing Inverse Perspective Mapping using opencv C++. I am following [this](https://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/source-code-inverse-perspective-mapping-c-opencv/) code to get the desired result. Please have a look at the result.

[[image]
[image]

I am using opencv c++ [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap) function. In addition to the current result I need to how to project a pixel from the source image to the distination image. i.e if I click on the pixel (320, 140), how would I get the corresponding pixel i.e (0, 0) in the distination picture.

```
void remap(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray map1, InputArray map2, int interpolation, int borderMode=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=Scalar())
```

I have the calculated the arguments map1, map2. I guess I have to use them but i don't know how.

Comment: If you are using the code you mentioned then Just use                            cv::Point2d applyHomographyInv(const cv::Point2d& _point); to project your points

Comment: Notice that function is calling applyHomography( _point, m_H_inv )  which uses a pre-calculated inverse transformation matrix.